# Delivery List (DL) or Mailing List for Texts

Tags: contacts, sms, contact-groups

I have a group of friends who like board games, and want me to text them any time we have a board game pick up night come up. But as friends move away or new friends are made I want to update this list.

At this point the list is a couple dozen people long and so manually texting that many people on short notice is hard. I'd like a 'few button clicks away' way of sending all of them a single, simple, text. IE "Board games tonight at my house at six!"

### The Question

Is there a series of operations (on any app) that will let me keep a list of phone numbers that I can conveniently group text?

### Complications

- I will routinely add and remove numbers from this list. (basically a Delivery List)
- I won't have access to other communications platforms for these people. (can't make them use an app or connect to their facebook or anything like that)

### Other Notes

- I'm willing to use pretty much any app if it does this (and isn't blatantly evil)

Comment: Ah! Much clearer now. I had a completely different picture before. You could use the "groups" functionality in the "people"/contacts app for that. Could you check if [this approach](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/create-contact-list-texting-android-30872.html) works for you?

Comment: I appear to have 'contacts' instead of 'people' and I can't find any groups options within it. I'm not sure if this is a version of android issue (BLU studio energy 2 running  Android version 5.0 as the about page puts it) or if it's due to the oem changes. >.< I wish it worked, it looks like what I want.

Comment: I just checked on my Android 6 device. Found the group function in the contacts app, but could not figure how to send a message to a group. Maybe you'd need a [3rd party SMS app](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_shortmessage#group_81) for that (link goes to my site, but I haven't tried any of those apps, had no need yet). Pulse SMS reportedly has that feature, but comes with trackers. Ah: QKSMS, preferably from F-Droid (no trackers in the F-Droid version) should do. Please confirm if it does, so I can sum up an answer :)

Comment: After some work with QKSMS (also a big fan of fdroid ^_^) I believe they do NOT have this functionality. Instead their stuff appears to be referencing the ability to set messages with multiple recipients to either run as a 'group message' or as a series of texts in their options menu.

Comment: Yuck. Same thing is offered by the default SMS app shipping with Android. Sorry, then I'm out of ideas.